# How do I access road traffic data in Android?

Tags: java, android, location, traffic

Is there a way I can access traffic data from Android? I would like to get both area traffic and traffic on a route - for example, I might want to get the traffic on I-76 in the Philadelphia area, or I might want to get the traffic along a route between an address in Philadelphia and one in Allentown.

Answer (score 0):

BING's REST service returns JSON or XML traffic information.  There is a BING SDK available you can use that is quite handy.

BING REST:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx

BING Android SDK:
http://bingmapsandroidsdk.codeplex.com/

Comment: Bing only reports traffic incidents. What I want is to access travel times.